# How to execute multiple commands automatically using ant?

Tags: ant

I Have n number of rbinfo files in my directory structure.

For eg: I have StateRB.rbinfo file in the directory structure \wt\lifecycle. To execute this file i run the below ant script:

```
<exec executable="${WT_HOME}/bin/ResourceBuild.bat">
    <arg value="wt.lifecycle.StateRB"/>
</exec>
```

This works perfectly fine.

Similarily I have RoleRB.rbinfo file in the location \wt\project and this can be executed using:

```
<exec executable="${WT_HOME}/bin/ResourceBuild.bat">
    <arg value="wt.project.RoleRB"/>
</exec>
```

Note: basically arg value will be folder structure.file name

If I have to run n rbinfo files I need to include the ant scripts n times. Please can any one suggest if there is any simpler way to run these files automatically without much manual work?

Comment: I edited your post. Next time, do it by yourself: "I" is spelt "I", in uppercase. And code blocks need 4 spaces at the bedinning of every line. There is a button in the editor that adds them for you.

Comment: can't you change your ResourceBuild.bat support multiple files?

Comment: @ Izprgmr- No I am not supposed to change anything in that bat file.

Comment: Probably can be done using the Ant apply task: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/apply.html